# Use of word late

Tags: word-usage, honorifics

If Mr. Peter Smith has died,
is it ok to use "Mrs. Peter Smith (late)" for his wife?

Comment: It is now either very old-fashioned or _very_ formal to refer to somebody's wife as "Mrs Peter Smith".

Comment: During my lifetime (68 years) it was never usual to refer to a wife by her husband's Christian name after he had died. Though it was perfectly normal (in Britain) up to about the 1970s, and still is among some older people, to refer to Mrs Peter Smith if the husband is still alive and provided the couple are living together.  In this instance I think the expression you need, if it is for something formal, is 'Mrs Jane Smith, wife of the late Peter Smith'.

Comment: Technically it would be 'Mrs Jane Smith, widow of the late Peter Smith'

Answer (score 4):

*Late* describes only the deceased.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, in front of such a formidable contestant as Mr Barrie England, but I would :

- place "late" before the name (..., spouse of the late Peter Smith) ;
- refer as "late" only for recently deceased persons (say : one year), and not say "the late Cleopatra".